# Is there a word that describes a person whose given name and surname each contains but a single syllable?

Tags: single-word-requests, names, category

Is there a word that describes a person whose given name and surname each contains but a single syllable?

Some examples are:

- Mae West
- Bill Fold
- John Doe

Comment: Who's is a typo, should have been whose.

Comment: I suppose you could always just call them _disyllabic_. (Or, if you want to get really fancy and just start making up fancy-sounding words, _disyllabonymic_.)

Comment: Brings to mind Asimov's phrase (in _Fantastic Voyage_) of "...the monosyllabic grunt of Grant."

Comment: I'd like to get fancy and make up fancy-sounding words but shorter ones.

Comment: If you treat the whole name in terms of metrical feet, Mae West is a spondee, and John Paul Jones is a molossus.

Comment: If you’re into ethnic profiling, you could just call them _Chinese_.

Answer (score 5):

The best I can think of is to say that their names are disyllabic duonyms, making them disyllabic-duonymic.

Such an answer though is in the realm of fun word games with obscure terms, rather than anything of much use in real English use. Don't say anyone is disyllabic-duonymic, except perhaps as a joke, aimed at a rather nerdy audience.

Comment: Oho! Even better than my _disyllabonymic_: _disyllaboduonymic_! :-D

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet well, at least *duonym* is attested, though more often of compound words than personal names, and I see you also hit on *disyllabic*, which isn't even being forced into unusual service as it goes. And that's about as much as I can say to justify either of us!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet One night also consider using the perfectly well-attested *binomial* here instead of *duonym*. Think for example of ***taxonomic binomials***, which are big-endian genus–species pairings of names. In contrast, *John Wayne* would be a little-endian binomial. I dunno, I might try going for the at-first-glance-contradictory *monosyllabic binomials* myself.

Comment: @tchrist though binomial is particularly associated with Latin binomial naming conventions. Thus recommending against unless it matches well.